# Inconsistent or incorrect text in primary phase info box

Tags: bug, status-completed, election

The second last paragraph in the info box on the side of the [primary phase](https://stackoverflow.com/election?tab=primary) page states:

> The primary is not binding; nominees may withdraw at their discretion at any point during the nomination phase.

Shouldn't "nomination phase" be "primary phase"?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Did you miss the date on the question?

Comment: @Josh Caswell: Because it hasn't been fixed?

Comment: @JoshCaswell I don't see a [meta-tag:status-completed] tag on it, so that could be why, don't you think? Also, he removed what is now obsolete...

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never, right?

Primary text is about primaries... with you in the next build.